# Why is my simple Google Maps demo not working on JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, jsfiddle

See http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/7g37Y/. The map is not being displayed.

It works on Yui (the code in the comments at the bottom of JS), but why not with the basic `addDomListener`?

Comment: look at the console it says `google is not defined`

Comment: I am not seeing any errors on FF console. Besides, `maps/api/js` is being loaded in HTML, so I would expect `google` to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the API from the **left sidebar** under **External resources**.

Add `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` and hit the **+** sign to add the API to the external resources that will be loaded.

If you use the `addDomListener` then use **`No wrap - in <head>`** in **Frameworks and extensions**.

Your map will work fine.